# How to run a TL-WDN3200 N600 wireless USB stick on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, usb, ubuntu-drivers

I'm running a PC with recently installed 14.04 replacing Windows.

I Need to run a TL-WDN3200 N600 wireless USB stick for urgent wi-fi access, but it seems to be only configured for Windows, how can I do that?

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Answer (score 0):

wikidevi.com states that the driver for the device is `rt2800usb` which is included in kernel[https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WDN3200] in Ubuntu 14.04 (assuming you're running no exotic setup, which you forgot to mention). It has to be a blacklisting problem. Check out https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Drivers and setup the right driver to be loaded.